# Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: jmeter

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jmeter

I would like to know about how to pass array value in the jMeter for oracle stored procedure.

Below details setup already but which is not working.Please help me on this.

**Oracle PL/SQL:**

```
PROCEDURE Get_User(
   p_input1                     IN  VARCHAR2,
   p_input2                     IN  VARCHAR2,
   p_input3                     IN  VARCHAR2,
   p_input4                     IN  SCHEMA.TABLE1.COLUMN1%TYPE,
   arr_user_names               IN  SCHEMA2.CUSTOM_TYPE_TABLE,
   p_user_name_out              OUT VARCHAR2,
   p_address_out                OUT SCHEMA.TABLE1.COLUMN1%TYPE,
   arr_result_set               OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);


create or replace type CUSTOM_TYPE as object( name VARCHAR2(30),salary  NUMBER(5,2));

create or replace type CUSTOM_TYPE_TABLE is table of CUSTOM_TYPE;
```

**Query:**

```
call SCHEMA1.PKG1.Get_User(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

**Parameter Value:**

```
INVAL1,INVAL3,INVAL3,INVAL4,'users':[{'name':'all'}],OUT,OUT,OUT
```

**Parameter Type:**

```
VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,VARCHAR,ARRAY,OUT VARCHAR,OUT VARCHAR,OUT -10
```

**Variables Name:**

```
p_input1,p_input2,p_input3,p_input4,arr_user_names,p_user_name_out,p_address_out,arr_result_set
```

**ResultSet variable name:**

```
p_user_name_out,p_address_out,arr_result_set
```

**Error: Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: 'users':[{'name':'all'}**

Comment: CUSTOM_TYPE is name and salary, where's the salary in input ? also does your query works in normal JDBC?

Comment: Yes, salary is optional, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into [AbstractJDBCTestElement.setArgument()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/src/protocol/jdbc/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/AbstractJDBCTestElement.java#L413) function I fail to see [Types.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#ARRAY) clause so my expectation is that you not be able to implement this using built-in JMeter JDBC Test Elements.

I would recommend considering switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) where you will have full control of your logic flow. See [Using Array Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) tutorial for more details if needed.

Comment: Then do I have to entire code to execute a procedure and check the response in groovy?

Comment: If yes related to the connection configuration, do I have to create everything or I can make use of the JDBC Connection Configuration of jMeter?

Comment: You can instantiate the connection using JDBC Connection Configuration like: `java.sql.Connection conn = org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection("your_variable_name_here");` . Other logic, i.e. preparing and executing the query and working with results needs to be done in Groovy completely.